# KnockoutJS on WordPress not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, knockout.js

I have KnockoutJS loaded (or probably—loaded) on this WordPress website and KnockoutJS in particular doesn't seem to work (see below):

http://dev.boltonremote.com/test-2/

The thing is, I don't think it's my browser or the site not loading JS properly, because:
1.) NumeralJS works;
2.) Ordinary JS works;
3.) Bootstrap, too.

That's a custom page in WordPress.  I had to declare the CDNs and write the script raw on the page instead of putting it inside the page editor.  But I believe that wasn't the case since I wrote a numeralJS script on the page too, and it worked.

So, does anyone know if Knockout is just not tested or proven not to load in WordPress, or is there some special way to load KnockoutJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, instead of:

```
<div class="liveExample"> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /* omitted */
    </script>    
    <form data-bind="submit: addItem">
        /* omitted */
    </form>
</div>
```

Rearrange so your <script /> block follows the <form />:

```
<div class="liveExample"> 
    <form data-bind="submit: addItem">
        /* omitted */
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /* omitted */
    </script>    
</div>
```

You are executing knockout at a position on the page where the elements that are data-bound have not yet been defined, and so are not visible to knockout.

Comment: @vm7488 No problems; it's stumped me before.  Another way to prevent this is to wrap it in the jQuery ready function which will execute after the DOM is ready: `$(function () { /* knockout stuff here */ });`